# OpenLayers vector features drawn outside map not wrapping date line

Tags: openlayers

I use an OpenLayers map, with the option wrappingDateLine=false.

I am drawing Vector Features in a Vector Layer, including each feature a point with a label. One of them appears outside the map, in the black zone where it should be the "next" map in case wrappingDateLine=true.

Is there an equivalent parameter for the Layer or the feature to tell them to be drawn between longitude -180,180?

Comment: I don't think so. Any chance of a jsfiddle or similar to illustrate the problem?

Comment: I found the problem, is a problem of frames definition, some of the points I am getting them avobe 180º. I am going to correct it to check the frame and substract 180º if its from 0 to 360. Thanks